# Count how many times a button has been clicked without decorators (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So I am making a tic tac toe game with tkinter.  However, when I bump up the turn value I get an attribute error: 'function' object has no attribute 'called'.  I am doing this so the computer does not skip it's turn

```
def player_move(widget):
    if widget["o"] not in ("o", "x"):
        widget["text"] = "o"
        widget["state"] = "disabled"
        player_move.called += 1  #The part I want to add to
        computer_move()

def computer_move():
    # computer moves 2nd time
    if i["text"] == "  ":
        i["text"] = "x"
        i["state"] = "disabled"
    else:
        c["text"] = "x"
        c["state"] = "disabled"
    if player_move.called == 1 and c["text"] == "x":
        print("whgwhgg") #Just for testing
```

Comment: outside functions create normal variable `player_move_called = 0` (not some strange `player_move.called` with dot)  - it will create global variable with start value `0`. And later use `global player_move_called` inside  `player_move` to inform function that you want use external/global variable instead of local one. In `computer_move` use `player_move_called` too, but you don't have to use `global player_move_called` because you don't modify value of `player_move_called`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to create `player_move.called` with some value before you add +1 to this variable (but create it after you create function `player_move()`)

```
def player_move(widget):
    # ...
    # add 1 to existing variable
    player_move.called += 1  #The part I want to add to

# create variable with some value 
player_move.called = 0
```